# user input events in OSX

Tags: macos

I would like to do statistics on different events in OSX. What would be an easy way to track user input events in OSX(mouse clicks and moves, app focused, menus clicked, etc)? May be there is some log file with at least some of this information?

Comment: I hope that this is hard to do on purpose, because the spyware possibilities would be endless.